# Does Admob work with iPhone OS 3.0?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, admob

I want to use Admob to display advertisements in one of my apps. I have registered for Admob, but when I try to use it with the iPhone 3.0 SDK I'm seeing errors.  Is it possible to use Admob with this version of the SDK?

Comment: Note that all applications submitted to the App Store must now be built using the 4.x SDK: http://developer.apple.com/news/ios/archives/2010/june/ .  You can still target 3.0, but you're going to want to upgrade to the iPhone 4.x SDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> AdMob iPhone ads are customized
>   specifically for iPhone and
>   iTouchdevices with OS 2.0 and above

[AdMob iPhone SDK Link](http://developer.admob.com/wiki/IPhone#Getting_Started_with_AdMob_iPhone_Ads)